# The pumping lemma for the context free languages

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I am trying to use the pumping lemma to show this is not a context
free language
$$
L = \{a^n b^{2n} a^n\mid n\ge 0\}
$$

My idea is fist assume it is a CFG language and let $n$ be the pumping lemma
integer.

Then let $u=a^n b^{2n} a^n$ be a string. I am going to use to prove it is not
a cfg language

Since $u=vwxyz$ and must follow all three conditions for the lemma.

So

$|wy|>0$ and $|wxy|\le n$ thus now I chose the first group of $a$ in the left of my string

and do

$vw^2xy^2z$ since $wy$ cannot include $b$, my $wxy$ string includes all $a$.

So then

$v w^2 x^2 z\notin L$ because $a^{n+1} b^{2n} a^n$ is not in language.

But am I correct?

Comment: You don't get to pick where the substring $wxy$ resides; you have to get a contradiction in every possible case. In this problem there are five places where $wxy$ may be: (1) in the first group of $a$s, (2) overlapping the first group $a$s and the $b$s, (3) in the $b$s, (4) overlapping the $b$s and the second group of $a$s, and (5) in the last group of $a$s.

Comment: There's no way to assign w, x, and y no matter what p is. W and y have to contain all three sections of the string, the same amount of `a`s from each side, and the same number of `b`s as `a`s. One of them has to contain both `b`s and `a`s. Try multiplying that. It immediately breaks the grammar.